# The most efficient way to draw in SkiaSharp without using PaintSurface event

Tags: wpf, skiasharp

An extension of this [question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99300/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-sksurface-outside-of-the-paintsurface-event). I'm using `SkiaSharp` to draw shapes with `OpenGL`. Most of code samples for WPF suggest using `SKElement` control and get reference to the drawing surface inside `PaintSurface` event. I need reference to drawing surface al the time, not only inside of this event, so I'm using `SKBitmap` and `SKCanvas` and send the output to `Image` control in WPF.

**XAML**

```
<Canvas x:Name="ScreenControl" />
```

**CS**

```
var bmp = new SKBitmap((int)ScreenControl.ActualWidth, (int)ScreenControl.ActualHeight);
var canvas = new SKCanvas(bmp);
var image = new Image
{
  Stretch = Stretch.Fill
};

canvas.DrawText("Demo", new SKPoint(20, 20), new SKPaint { TextSize = 20 });

var index = 0;
var clock = new Timer();
var wrt = bmp.ToWriteableBitmap();

image.Source = wrt;

clock.Interval = 100;
clock.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
{
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
  {
    var wrt = bmp.ToWriteableBitmap(); // Potentially slow line #1

    canvas.Clear();
    canvas.DrawText((index++).ToString(), new SKPoint(20, 20), new SKPaint { TextSize = 20 });
    image.Source = wrt;                // Potentially slow line #2
    image.InvalidateVisual();
  }));
};
clock.Start();

ScreenControl.Children.Clear();
ScreenControl.Children.Add(image);
```

**Project**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.WPF" Version="2.80.3-preview.18" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Question**

Is there a way to draw faster, specifically, without recreating bitmap `bmp.ToWriteableBitmap()` and without changing image source every time `image.Source = wrt`? Back buffer or something related?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Skia's SKElement:

```
<Grid>
    <skia:SKElement PaintSurface="OnPaintSurface" IgnorePixelScaling="True" />
</Grid>
```

And draw in OnPaintSurface:

```
    private void OnPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        // the the canvas and properties
        var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;

        // make sure the canvas is blank
        canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

        // draw some text
        var paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Color = SKColors.Black,
            IsAntialias = true,
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
            TextAlign = SKTextAlign.Center,
            TextSize = 24
        };
        var coord = new SKPoint(e.Info.Width / 2, (e.Info.Height + paint.TextSize) / 2);
        canvas.DrawText("SkiaSharp", coord, paint);
    }
```